# Reshape list from long to wide in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a list in long format as follows:

```
name days N
A     1   80
A     2   90
B     1   70
B     3   85
B     5   100
C     2   80
C     5   95
```

I would like to obtain the following output:

```
days   1  2  3  4  5
A      80 90 NA NA NA
B      70 NA 85 NA 100
C      NA 80 NA NA 95
```

I tried the function reshape and obtained the error:

```
reshape(data, idvar = data[,1], timevar = [,3], direction = "wide")
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , timevar) : undefined columns selected
```

`

Comment: This should help you ; Long to wide using `tidyr` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146287/long-to-wide-data-with-tidyr

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "name",
  timevar = "days"
)
```

which gives

```
  name N.1 N.2 N.3 N.5
1    A  80  90  NA  NA
3    B  70  NA  85 100
6    C  NA  80  NA  95
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, 
              names_from = days,
              values_from = N)
```

To change the name of the first column you can do `names(df)[1] <- "days"` after you run the above code.

**Output**

```
  name    `1`   `2`   `3`   `5`
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A        80    90    NA    NA
2 B        70    NA    85   100
3 C        NA    80    NA    95
```

Note: the output is a `tibble` object which does allow for column names to be numbers, but when accessing them you will need to use backticks. Generally, column names as numbers isn't advisable and is why in base `R` `data.frame` will fix column names that start with a number. The solution posted by @ThomasIsCoding outputs a `data.frame` object, which is why the columns have an "N." prefix.